# Undefined [controller]_path for route with two params

Tags: routes, phoenix-framework

I created a controller in my Phoenix application called `ProgressController`. This is what my router file look like:

```erlang
defmodule MyTestApp.Router do
  use MyTestApp.Web, :router

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", MyTestApp do
    pipe_through :api

    get "/users/:user_id/courses/:course_id", ProgressController, :show
  end
end
```

When I run `mix phoenix.routes` it outputs:

```
progress_path  GET   /users/:user_id/courses/:course_id  MyTestApp.ProgressController :show
```

And I have the following test, which uses `progress_path`:

```erlang
test "shows the user's progress in the given course", %{conn: conn} do
  # prepare some stuff
  conn = get conn, progress_path(conn, :show, %{user_id: 1, course_id: 7})
  # assert some stuff
end
```

`progress_path` is the same name that `mix phoenix.routes` gave me, and I am surprise do see this error message when running my tests:

Compiling 11 files (.ex)

```
** (CompileError) test/controllers/progress_controller_test.exs:12: undefined function progress_path/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_require.ex:57: anonymous fn/2 in Kernel.ParallelRequire.spawn_requires/5

20:34:46.402 [error] GenServer #PID<0.242.0> terminating
** (CompileError) test/controllers/progress_controller_test.exs:12: undefined function progress_path/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_module.erl:113: :elixir_module.do_compile/5
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) src/elixir.erl:223: :elixir.erl_eval/3
    (elixir) src/elixir.erl:211: :elixir.eval_forms/4
    (elixir) src/elixir_compiler.erl:66: :elixir_compiler.eval_compilation/3
    (elixir) src/elixir_lexical.erl:17: :elixir_lexical.run/3
    (elixir) src/elixir_compiler.erl:30: :elixir_compiler.quoted/3
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_require.ex:57: anonymous fn/2 in Kernel.ParallelRequire.spawn_requires/5
```

I narrowed down the problem to the fact that there are 2 params in that route's URL, but I can't figure out how to actually fix this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of search, trial and errors, I discovered that the `path` function expects a list of params, not a `Map`. Like this:

```erlang
conn = get conn, progress_path(conn, :show, 1, 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution looking at the last documentation.

To take the path_helper you have to set:

```
Routes.page_path(@conn, :name)
```