# undefined _path after mix test

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have routes `/teams` and a path `team_path` via `mix phx.routes`. However i am receiving `undefined function team_path/3`

below is my test code:

```
describe "create team" do
   test "renders team when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
      conn = post(conn, team_path(conn, :create, team: @team_attrs))

      assert %{"id" => id} = json_response(conn, 201)["data"]
    end

    test "renders errors when data is invalid", %{conn: conn} do
      conn = post(conn, team_path(conn, :create, team: @invalid_attrs))
      assert json_response(conn, 400)["errors"] != %{}
    end
  end
```

Additional infos:

- Phoenix 1.4-beta
- phoenix_swagger installed
- its an API so everything is under scope `/api`

Comment: See if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812524/undefined-controller-path-for-route-with-two-params

Answer (score 0):

I think the payload to the POST call goes in the `post()` function, while you have put it in the `team_path` helper. Could you try:

```
conn = post(conn, team_path(conn, :create), %{team: @team_attrs})
```

Link to docs for reference:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#post/3

Comment: still the same and receiving same error:

`Compilation error in file test/futsal_web/controllers/team_controller_test.exs ==
** (CompileError) test/futsal_web/controllers/team_controller_test.exs:63: undefined function team_path/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:677: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:209: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6`

Comment: Could you run `mix phx.routes` and verify that `team_path` exists and has a `:create` action?

Comment: yes it has :

`team_path  POST  /api/teams  FutsalWeb.TeamController :create
           *     /api        FutsalWeb.PhoenixSwagger.Plug.SwaggerUI [otp_app: :futsal, swagger_file: "swagger.json"]`

Comment: Is your test suite importing all router helpers? Normally you just need `FutsalWeb.Router.Helpers` or similar, which contains the routing helper functions (usually it's in `conn_case.ex`). I'm not sure how PhoenixSwagger works, but you may need to import the Swagger Routers' helpers in `conn_test.ex`.